# Correct Nodejs mssql parameterized LIKE query syntax

Tags: sql-server, node.js, wildcard, parameterized

Using Nodejs and `mssql` package for SQL Server, I understand normal `SELECT` query with parameters:

```
aVar = "somestring"; // used as example, the real input is from a web form
request = new sql.Request(conn)
.input('aParam', sql.NVarChar(200), aVar);
q = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE theColumn = @aParam";
request.query(q, function(err, record) { ...
```

Those work just fine. Changing this to use `LIKE`, and I cannot get it to work. I've tried single quote before the % character, after, around it, just around the string, the whole thing, etc. Doing this:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE theColumn LIKE " + "'%@aParam%'";
```

does not result in any errors, but returns no results. All other attempts with those single quotes results in query syntax errors. I cant seem to locate any documentation for parameterizing queries with wildcards. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to do this is mentioned here - https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/332.

But in short:

```js
q = `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE theColumn LIKE '%' + @aParam + '%';`;
```

Answer (score -2):

Unless you writing low level driver/worker, I would recommend to use any ORM:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

const MyTable = sequelize.define('myTable', {
  theColumn: Sequelize.STRING
});

const aVar = 'somestring'; 

const results = await MyTable.findAll({
    where: {
        theColumn: { $like: `%${aVar}%` }
    }
  });
})
console.dir(results);
```

`await` can be used only inside `async` functions. For Framework supporting this out of the box take a look at Koa.js https://github.com/koajs/koa

Comment: Appreciate the ORM recommendation, I'll likely end up moving to that, but was hoping for a solution using current mssql package.